# Probability of difference between 2 sets

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How can I prove $Pr[X] - Pr[Y] \leq Pr[X\setminus Y]$ if if $X$ and $Y$ are events? I have to utilize the principle of inclusion exclusion.

This is my solution so far.

Let A and B some events of $\Omega$. Then A and B can either disjoint events or non disjoint events.

Let A and B be disjoint events

If A and B are disjoint then they have no elements in common. That means they have no outcomes that are in both events. The difference between  P r[X] and P r[Y] is the difference between their probability values. The RHS, $P r[X\setminus Y]$ can be seen as the elements of events A not in the event B. Since these cases are disjoint then ALL the elements in A cannot be in B so $[X\setminus Y]$ is equal to Pr[X].

After that I am stuck and I don't think I am using PIE. Is my approach on the right track? If not what is the answer to this problem?

Edit: My new approach

Using the principle of inclusion-exclusion, we can write:

Pr[X] = Pr[X∩Y] + Pr[X\Y]
Pr[Y] = Pr[X∩Y] + Pr[Y\X]

where X\Y represents the event that X occurs but Y does not, and X∩Y represents the event that both X and Y occur.

Substituting these equations into the inequality to be proved, we get:

Pr[X] - Pr[Y] ≤ Pr[X\Y]

Pr[X∩Y] + Pr[X\Y] - (Pr[X∩Y] + Pr[Y\X]) ≤ Pr[X\Y]

Pr[X\Y] - Pr[Y\X] ≤ Pr[X\Y]

Pr[X\Y] ≤ Pr[X\Y] + Pr[Y\X]

This inequality holds because probabilities are non-negative, which means that Pr[Y\X] is non-negative. Therefore, we have:

Pr[X\Y] - Pr[Y\X] ≤ Pr[X\Y] + Pr[Y\X]

Simplifying this inequality, we get:

2Pr[X\Y] ≤ Pr[X\Y] + Pr[Y\X]

Pr[X\Y] ≤ Pr[Y\X] + Pr[X\Y]/2

Since Pr[X\Y]/2 is non-negative, this inequality holds. Therefore, we have:

Pr[X\Y] ≤ Pr[X] - Pr[X∩Y]

Substituting this inequality into the original inequality, we get:

Pr[X] - Pr[Y] ≤ Pr[X\Y] ≤ Pr[X] - Pr[X∩Y]

Therefore, we have proved that Pr[X] - Pr[Y] ≤ Pr[X\Y] using the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Is this correct?

Comment: If I were you I would look at $\Pr(X \cap Y), \Pr(X \cap Y^c), \Pr(X^c \cap Y), \Pr(X^c \cap Y^c)$.  For example $\Pr(X \backslash Y)= \Pr(X \cap Y^c)$ and $\Pr(X)= \Pr(X \cap Y)+ \Pr(X \cap Y^c)$

Comment: @Henry what does the c notation mean? I'm new to probability

Comment: $X^c$ is the event of *not* $X$, i.e. $\Omega \backslash X$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principle of inclusion-exclusion (for two events) states that
$$ P(X\cup Y) = P(X) + P(Y) - P(X\cap Y).$$
We then have
\begin{align}
    P(X\backslash Y) &= P(X) - P(X\cap Y) \\
                     &= P(X\cup Y) - P(Y) \\
                     &\ge P(X) - P(Y),
\end{align}
where the second equality follows from the principle.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, note that $({X\backslash Y})\cup Y =X \cup Y\supseteq X $. Thus, [monotonicity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Probability_Measure_is_Monotone) of the probability measure, and ${X\backslash Y}$ and $Y$ being mutually exclusive gives

$$P(({X\backslash Y})\cup Y)=P({X\backslash Y})+P(Y)\geq P(X),$$

and rearranging gives the desired result.